# Amazon Alexa Matter SDK

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

How we can fetch and control Alexa app accessories from Different Android App. In apple ecosystem I  observed, third party apps can fetch accessories from Apple Homekit using the Apple HomeKit APIs.
Is there any similar APIs for Alexa App.

- Scenario:

1. Create TestApp
2. Fetch Alexa Matter and Non-Matter Accessories(Devices)
3. Control(On/Off a bulb) accessories from TestApp

Answer (score 0):

Alexa has backend RESTful APIs to fetch and control devices.
See https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-smart-properties/alexa-for-residential-rest-api.html